# Issue with EntityManager with Tapestry and JPA

Tags: database, jpa, dao, tapestry, entitymanager

I've been trying to go from Tapestry-hibernate to Tapestry-jpa.

I've followed the user guide http://tapestry.apache.org/integrating-with-jpa.html , however, I'm experiencing some, to me unknown, exceptions and I have no more ideas how to solve it.

```
2013-07-25 12:36:20.608:WARN::failed app: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception constructing service 'RegistryStartup': Error invoking service contribution method org.apache.tapestry5.jpa.JpaModule.startupEarly(EntityManagerManager, boolean): No persistence providers available for "DemoUnit" after trying the following discovered implementations: NONE
2013-07-25 12:36:20.608:WARN::Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@2bbd9de3{/addressbook,C:\Users\eivaore\workspaces\training\addressbook\src\main\webapp}
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception constructing service 'RegistryStartup': Error invoking service contribution method org.apache.tapestry5.jpa.JpaModule.startupEarly(EntityManagerManager, boolean): No persistence providers available for "DemoUnit" after trying the following discovered implementations: NONE
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.obtainObjectFromCreator(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:75)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.createObject(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:54)
    at $Runnable_11a5a7e5614b.delegate(Unknown Source)
    at $Runnable_11a5a7e5614b.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.performRegistryStartup(RegistryImpl.java:325)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryWrapper.performRegistryStartup(RegistryWrapper.java:80)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.init(TapestryFilter.java:118)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:713)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at runjettyrun.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:97)
2013-07-25 12:36:20.642:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8888
```

My `persistence.xml` is placed at `src/main/resources/META-INF/` and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="DemoUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"    value="jdbc:h2:mem:test" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user"   value="sa" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation"    value="create-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level"     value="fine"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I am using it in my DAO class like this:

```
package com.example.addressbook.data.impl;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.PostInjection;

import com.example.addressbook.data.CelebrityDao;
import com.example.addressbook.entities.Celebrity;
import com.example.addressbook.entities.Occupation;
import com.example.addressbook.util.Formats;

public class CelebrityDaoImpl implements CelebrityDao {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "DemoUnit")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public CelebrityDaoImpl() {
    }

    public void add(Celebrity celebrity) {
        entityManager.persist(celebrity);
    }

    public Celebrity get(long id) {
        return entityManager.find(Celebrity.class, id);
    }

    public List<Celebrity> getAll() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Celebrity",
                Celebrity.class).getResultList();

    }

    public List<Celebrity> getRange(long startIndex, long endIndex) {
        TypedQuery<Celebrity> query = entityManager.createQuery(
                "SELECT c FROM Celebrity where c.id BETWEEN :idStart AND :idEnd", 
                Celebrity.class);
        query.setParameter("idStart", startIndex);
        query.setParameter("idEnd", endIndex);

        return query.getResultList();
    }

    @PostInjection
    public void prepare() {
        add(new Celebrity("Britney", "Spearce",
                Formats.parseDate("12/02/1981"), Occupation.SINGER, "", true));
        add(new Celebrity("Bill", "Clinton", Formats.parseDate("08/19/1946"),
                Occupation.POLITICIAN, "", true));
        add(new Celebrity("Placido", "Domingo",
                Formats.parseDate("01/21/1941"), Occupation.SINGER, "", true));
        add(new Celebrity("Albert", "Einstein",
                Formats.parseDate("03/14/1879"), Occupation.SCIENTIST, "", true));
        add(new Celebrity("Ernest", "Hemingway",
                Formats.parseDate("07/21/1899"), Occupation.WRITER, "", true));
        add(new Celebrity("Luciano", "Pavarotti",
                Formats.parseDate("10/12/1935"), Occupation.SINGER, "", true));
        add(new Celebrity("Ronald", "Reagan", Formats.parseDate("02/06/1911"),
                Occupation.POLITICIAN, "", true));
        add(new Celebrity("Pablo", "Picasso", Formats.parseDate("10/25/1881"),
                Occupation.ARTIST, "", true));
        add(new Celebrity("Blaise", "Pascal", Formats.parseDate("06/19/1623"),
                Occupation.SCIENTIST, "", true));
        add(new Celebrity("Isaac", "Newton", Formats.parseDate("01/04/1643"),
                Occupation.SCIENTIST, "", true));
        add(new Celebrity("Antonio", "Vivaldi",
                Formats.parseDate("03/04/1678"), Occupation.COMPOSER, "", true));
        add(new Celebrity("Niccolo", "Paganini",
                Formats.parseDate("10/27/1782"), Occupation.MUSICIAN, "", true));
        add(new Celebrity("Johannes", "Kepler",
                Formats.parseDate("12/27/1571"), Occupation.SCIENTIST, "", true));
        add(new Celebrity("Franz", "Kafka", Formats.parseDate("07/03/1883"),
                Occupation.WRITER, "", true));
        add(new Celebrity("George", "Gershwin",
                Formats.parseDate("09/26/1898"), Occupation.COMPOSER, "", true));
    }

    public int count() {
        return getAll().size();
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try just using @Inject instead of @PersistenceContext? Is the error the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project seems to have no JPA implementations in the classpath. Try adding Eclipse-JPA by following the instructions in http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.eclipse.persistence%7Corg.eclipse.persistence.jpa%7C2.5.1%7Cjar.